# Function of “ever”

Tags: sentence-meaning

I didn’t do my homework on Monday, and I did do my homework on Tuesday.

“I **ever** didn’t do my homework” is wrong because I did do my homework on Tuesday.

Then, is just saying “I didn’t do my homework” right because I didn’t do my homework on Monday?

Comment: You may want to familiarize yourself with the word **never** and then edit your question.  You will want to understand the difference between *ever and never*.

Comment: _I ever didn't_ is incorrect. "I didn't ever do my homework" would mean that you never did it at all. You can say "I didn't do my homework on Monday, but I did do it on Tuesday."

Comment: @Kate Bunting I can’t omit “on Monday”? I want to say I didn’t do my homework.

Comment: You can omit it if it is clear that you are only talking about Monday!

Comment: @EllieK But James K told me not to edit the post once any comment is added..

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you!

Comment: @user142559 - You are encouraged to edit your post whenever it will help clarify the question you have asked.  If your question is unclear, you will usually find comments below it, like these comments, asking for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

***Getting started*** with **adverbs of frequency**

***ever*** is an **adverb**, like **never, often, sometimes, always, frequently**

***ever* is for negative interrogatives and interrogatives**:

Do you *ever swim* in the winter? Or: Don't you *ever swim* in the winter?
No, I *never* swim in the winter.

These adverbs go in front of the main verb if there is an auxiliary  (see above) and before the verb if there isn't one. Sometimes, they can go after the verb: She arrives late sometimes.

With **be** and an adjective, they precede the adjective:

Is he ever late?
No, he is never late.
Is she ever nice? No, she isn't ever nice.

Answer (score 0):

> I ever didn't do my homework.

This is not a correct sentence in any context. When a sentence uses an auxiliary verb (the *did* part of *didn't*), *ever* cannot go before that verb. In this case, it should go between the auxiliary verb and the main verb (*do*).

---

> I didn't ever do my homework.

This is a grammatically correct sentence, but the meaning is not what you want. *Ever* means "at all times". So this sentence means "At all times (during some unspecified period of time in the past), I did not do my homework."

---

If you want someone to know that you didn't do your homework on Monday, you should just say that.

> I didn't do my homework on Monday.

On the other hand, perhaps you want to someone to know that, *in general*, there are days when you do your homework and days when you do not. Your behavior on Monday is one example of your habits, but it is not the main idea.

In that case, you might say:

> Sometimes I don't do my homework.

Or:

> I don't always do my homework.

The use of *don't* instead of *didn't* means that your behavior is ongoing; it continues into the present.